# What is shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

What exactly is shell scripting?

And what is Bash, Korn, and Expect? I use a few commands in a Linux terminal, is that shell scripting too? Again I am confused what exactly is shell scripting?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell.htm

Answer (score 10):

Your terminal runs a [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) , probably [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) - korn, csh and others are similar shells with different features and syntax.

While you probably use it mostly to run commands, most shells are an interpreter for command language defined by that shell. Programs in that language is called a shell script. See [this howto](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for an overview of shell scripting in bash.

Comment: to find out path to bash, I do which bash. But how would I find out where Korn is??

Comment: @sai: You'd do `which ksh` since "ksh" is the name of the executable. In Bash, I prefer `type -a` over `which` because it will show you aliases and functions which may supersede an executable plus each location that an executable exists in directories in your path. Some versions of `which` don't give you that much information.

Answer (score 6):

Shell scripting is the process of creating a file containing several shell commands (i.e. `ls`, `cd`, `grep`, etc) than can then be executed.

bash and korn are both shells - they allow you to interface with the computer through a command line, rather than running programs by clicking on icons.

The purpose of shell scripting is to automate repetitive tasks, such as setting up an environment to launch a program, or checking to see if logfiles have changed, or archiving a directory (or set of directories) or any other number of tasks.

Check [this out](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/) for more info.

Comment: "The purpose of shell scripting is to automate repetitive tasks", Ohh you can do so much more then just this. That's the beauty of the unix design. http://128.10.19.20/research/technical_reports/1981/TR%2081-379.pdf

Comment: "any other number of tasks" ;) I guess I could have said "anything you want", since most (all?) shell languages are Turing complete..

Answer (score 4):

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define:+shell+script

Shell scripting lets you automate tasks that you do from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to being an interaction environment the shell (be it the original Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) or one of the many alternatives (ksh, csh, bash, zsh, tcsh, ...) with different or extended syntax) provides *programming language like features* (looping, conditionals, functions, variables...).

Shell scripting is more or less *writing a program in you favorite shell*.

The line between using the shell and scripting is fuzzy, but I'd put it near "solving a class of problems by writing some shell code that is smart in some way".

Comment: I don't think the line is fuzzy.  Although writing complex command lines is a similar activity, interactively sending commands to the shell is *not* scripting, while writing them into a file is.

Comment: @William: It does get fuzzy since you can use pipes, loops and conditionals on the command line. Whether a condition of being in a file is unconditionally necessary to constitute a "script" is a semantic argument.

Answer (score 0):

A shell allows you create one or more *pipelines* of processes. 
    One hallmark of the *pipes and filters* theme - is *combining together the tools - the tools are **filters** - e.g. ls, egrep, paste, bc, wc...* You can create your own filters/tools too - and combine them.
The shell defines the syntax for combining filters using *pipes*. It also gives you a way to test for condition, via the *if keyword* - and write loops. You can write functions too. 
   In short, you can write programs - using tools which are mostly there - and create very powerful, tailor made functionality to suite your needs - **very quickly**. This is scripting - combine and reuse existing tools as *scripts* in fruitful ways

For example, consider the pipeline
    `% seq 100 | paste -s -d '*'` 
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10...98*99*100

The person who wrote the **seq** filter would not have imagined **seq** used like above. The **seq** program, by itself, is simple. This ability to *arbitrarily connect* **seq** with **paste** (or some other filter tool) - makes it an extremely powerful concept.

For example, consider the pipeline
    `% seq 100 | paste -s -d '*' | bc` 
93326215443944152681699... 
 It takes the expression (as above) - and feeds it to **bc** - yet another filter - **bc** evaluates the multiplication expression.

In short, a *shell script* allows you to *combine/reuse* existing tools - with the flow control mechanisms like if, while... to create very powerful *programs* in a pretty short time.